# Ignore a specific error to display in azure pipeline

Tags: powershell, shell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

My pipeline exits with error code 1 once it completes, though I want to do it but I don't want to get that error message displayed in the error section of pipeline GUI.

Like we use  [##vso task.logissue type-error] to get a error message displayed ..can I have something similar to ignore a error code from getting displayed but at the same time my pipeline should exit.

Comment: Hey there :) Why would you need to do this? And what step produces the error?

Comment: I am having multiple errors which I echo and this bash exit code errors looks clumsy in between. In the end of script I pass exit 1 and the script does an exit and produces the error but I don't want it to get displayed over GUI.

Comment: You can probably write that output code to a file if you need to use it afterwards... But in general hard to say, consider adding some YAML to the question and maybe the screenshot as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clean Exit from an Azure Pipeline .yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66699024/clean-exit-from-an-azure-pipeline-yaml)